# I need centering flexbox columns in conteiner

Tags: css, flexbox, centering

My 3 images need to be in screen center. I use flexbox. After adding size to images all of them go to left. Also I can't throw off margin

[This is what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu7ZZ.jpg)

[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFNT0.jpg)

My cod:

```css
.collection {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
 
}
```

```html
 <ul class="collection">
        <li><a href="#"><img class="col-img" src="images/bouquets.jpeg" alt=""><p class="col-text">Букети</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img class="col-img" src="images/natural_flowers.jpeg" alt=""><p class="col-text">Живі квіти</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img class="col-img" src="images/own_bouquet.png" alt=""><p class="col-text">"Свій" букет</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you try `justify-content: center;`

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by absolutely positioning your p tag on top of your image. Use translate and top/left rules to move it to the center. Also make the a tag as display:block so it effectively covers the image. See below.

Edited:
There were a few small tweaks, the a tag had a 3 pixels below it which are space for descenders. This has been removed using line-height and means that images stack directly on top of each other. In the comments it was also stated that the images needed to be cropped and centered. This was done with display: flex on the anchor tag and then using align-self: center to prevent it from shrinking to the size of the parent div. Finally they were cropped using overflow:hidden. Now that the anchor tag is using flexbox the need to use inset and translate isn't needed as they center anyway.

Hope this helps

```css
.collection {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  line-height:1;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px #757575;
}

a p {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #A6BFEA;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px #757575;
  line-height:normal;
}

img {
  align-self:center;
  translate: auto -50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="collection">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="col-img" src="https://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">
      <p class="col-text">Букети</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="col-img" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/500/300" alt="">
      <p class="col-text">"Свій" букет</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="col-img" src="https://www.placecage.com/500/300" alt="">
      <p class="col-text">"Свій" букет</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Which bit doens't work, specifically? I can then tweak to suit.

Comment: I've had another look and it was slightly off centre due to padding-left on the ul tag so I have set this to zero and it's now fully centered.

Comment: Already work, but I don't understand why margin exists and how can I cut hight like in picture.

Comment: If you need to crop the image then you can set the li element to a specific height and user overflow:hidden and relative positioning to crop the image. I'll edit my answer and show you what I mean.

Comment: I've tweaked it to remove the tiny gap between images and also explained how to crop and center the images too.

Answer (score 0):

```
.collection {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
li {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.collection {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container p {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="collection">
        <li>
          <a href="#">        
            <div class="container">
              <img class="col-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x150/000/fff" alt="">
              <p class="col-text">Букети</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">        
            <div class="container">
              <img class="col-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x150/000/fff" alt="">
              <p class="col-text">Букети</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">        
            <div class="container">
              <img class="col-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x150/000/fff" alt="">
              <p class="col-text">Живі квіти</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```